# how to replace image source of an html file using vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

how to replace image source of an html file with an folder name in the given path of an address bar in visual studio 2010

please anyone can help me with required logic will be really appreciated

Comment: could you please explain more?

Comment: i have to search the folder name from the path entered in text box and replace the image source path of an html file with it.

Comment: What I understand is that you have an html file with an IMG tag and you want to change its SRC attribute. other than that, nothing. could you please explain more, a lot more?

Comment: yaa right i want to change src attribute and replace it with the file name in the path for example \\192.168.0.2\kpo\Employee-Backup\Jigar\6373889-6388505_6388663\6373889\6388505\6388663\html

Comment: this is the required path and i want to replace the src attribute with "" \6373889\6388505\63886633\html\""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two different paths

1- `String.Replace` to remove directory, but it may remove more than what you need.

```
var sourceDir = txtPath.Text; // \\192.168.0.2\kpo\Employee-Backup\Jigar\6373889-6388505_6388663
var html = File.ReadAllText("MyTest.html");

var cleanedHtml = string.Replace(html, source, "")
```

2- Use `HtmlAgility` library to load html, find `IMG` tags and replace `SRC` attribute of every `IMG` using `String.Replace`. Harder but safer.

update:

```
var separators = new char[] {
  Path.DirectorySeparatorChar,  
  Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar  
};

var pathParts = sourceDir.Split(separators);

var root = string.Join("\\", pathParts.Take(pathParts.Length - 4));
var last4 = string.Join("\\", pathParts.Skip(pathParts.Length - 4));
```

Comment: but the problem is that the text with which i wanna replace will not be default it must take the last four folders from the path every time i change the path in textbox.

Comment: @jigar I've updated my answer to show how to find last four folders

Comment: now one more help the code for replacing image source of an html file is execut

Comment: but in html file actually it isnt replacing the img src path

Comment: Dim html As String
        Dim clean As String
        html = File.ReadAllText(TextBox1.Text & "\article.html")
        clean = html.Replace(html, "<img src=""" & last)                    i have done the above program bt i am not able to replace the last four folder name in image source of the html file in the above code article.html is the filename and 'last' is the last four folder with which i want to replace the image source path of article.html file

Comment: `html.Replace(root, "")` this line removes the root so only last four directories remain. It does not care if it is `src` or something else.

Comment: but it is not replacing the content which i want to replace in the html file

Answer (score 0):

```
File.WriteAllText(TextBox1.Text & "\article.html", 
     File.ReadAllText(TextBox1.Text & "\article.html")
         .Replace("src=""img", " src=""/ielx5/" & last & "/img")
)
```

I did this and finally suceeded. Thank you for your help.